# Why is もっと pronounced "motto" but written "motsuto"?

Tags: hiragana, spelling

Word **もっと** is pronuncing as **motto** means more. But when writing It is **mo(も) tsu(っ) to(と)**.

Why is that ? I'm new to Japanese language.

Please tell me there are other commonly used words like this ? Please give me some examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a double consonant sound. It's denoted by the smaller size **つ**. So instead of the word being pronounced as **Mo-tsu-to**, it is pronounced **Mot-to** because of the **っ**. That is why you have two *t*'s instead of just Mo-to. This is similar to **かった** in which the actual pronunciation is **kat-ta** instead of **ka-tsu-ta.** Another consonant sound is added before **っ** that is similar to the one following it. That is why in both **もっと** and **かった** the tsu is replaced by a "t" because the kana following **っ** are **と** and **た**, which both start with a "t" sound. This is why it is called a double consonant sound.

Comment: You should just give him all the details, like the small Y kana.

Answer (score 7):

**That character is not exactly the tsu-character!**

The second character of **もっと** is called **sokuon**, it's not the normal hiragana 'つ'. The difference is that the sokuon is smaller (other than that, they are identical, so your question is totally understandable). For this reason it is also called small-tsu (or *chiisaitsu* in Japanese).

The sokuon is used to carry the consonant sound of the second character to the end of the first. In [rōmaji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese), that is represented by doubling the consonant, that's why もっと is romanized as **motto**. This change in pronunciation (from *moto* to *motto*) is not at all trivial, and it takes some time to get used to it.

There are other characters in Japanese that are small versions of others. There are, for example, the small 'ya' (ゃ), 'yu' (ゅ), 'yo' (ょ), used to create sounds like 'kya' (きゃ), 'shu' (しゅ), 'cho' (ちょ), and so on. This also happens in katakana, not only hiragana. Since you are a beginner, I totally recommend reading this: [Tae Kim's Guide to Japanese ‐ Hiragana](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/hiragana). It covers all those things about hiragana, and it's very well written (that's exactly what I used to learn!)